# background issue in openGl

Tags: opengl, graphics, texture-mapping, texture2d

hi i am making a simple game using openGl only ..... i made a main menu , set a background for it and some options , how ever when i Drawing the menu the background image turns to greenish color , by the way the last string in the menu i color it green and when i color it blue for example the background image turns to the same color plz help i will but the MainMenuDispaly function .

here is the pic

[image]

here is what i do :

[image]

every thing was done right except this :(

```
void MainMenuDis()
{
  glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
  glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    glVertex3f(-5,5,-6);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glVertex3f(-5,-5,-6);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glVertex3f(5,-5,-6);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    glVertex3f(5,5,-6);
  glEnd();

  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

  for(int i = 0 ; i  < 5 ; ++i)
  {
    MainMenuList[i].DrawString(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
  }

  Navigate.DrawString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12);

  glutSwapBuffers ();
  glFlush ();
}
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Immediate mode is deprecated.

Comment: @Sarge Borsch can u please tell me what is the right way to do it or any useful tutorial ....

Comment: You could look at e.g. [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) or [opengl-tutorial.org](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/). Working with shaders seems to be more complex at the first look, because it takes longer till you see the first results and you get into it, but you should take the time to learn it instead of the deprecated immediate mode.

Comment: deprecated immediate mode .... what is this mean ? @t.niese

Comment: OpenGL evolved over time, in the beginning there was the immediate mode for drawing (using `glBegin`, `glTexCoord2f`, `glVertex3f`, ...).   For better performance a new render mode was introduced (using Shaders and VBO). Immediate mode only remains for backwards compatibility of older applications. But as it is marked as `deprecated` you should not use it for new code. Because these features not only may be removed in future versions, but also may result in performance drawbacks. So for new projects (except if you need to develop for ancient hardware) should not use deprecated features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that you forgot that OpenGL is a state machine. I.e. it keeps the state of what it does last and applies it to the rest of it. You're drawing a textured quad, but that also incorporates all the other state you defined. Including the *color* you've set to draw your menu entries (which you shouldn't draw using glutBitmapString in the long term).

So you've to bring OpenGL into a state that is apropriate for drawing a textured quad. Now you should really use shaders and vertex arrays (in VBOs), because in modern OpenGL all the drawing details are controlled by the used shader, which is switched with a single line.

```
`glUseProgram(…);`
```

In your case however, using immediate mode in fixed function pipeline you've to set a number of things:

```
  glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glColor3f(1.,1.,1.);
  /* and probably a few more depending on what you're setting elsewhere */

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
  glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      …
```

Comment: yeah just adding glColoef(1,1,1); after glBegin(GL_QUADS) . thanks :)

Comment: @SaifSuleiman: You can call glColor outside of a glBegin/glEnd block perfectly well. I did that deliberately in the code snippet to exemplify the state machine of OpenGL.